# Windows 8 Slow boot from CHKDSK

Tags: windows-8, chkdsk

At our tech shop, we have 2 PCs set up for doing offline virus scanning, disk checking, etc. One PC runs Windows XP (and has an IDE controller available), and the other is running Windows 8. That is not the issue though

The issue is that when I put in a hard drive that has bad blocks, or *something* wrong with the file system, Windows 8 will automatically run a `CHKDSK`, with no prompt to cancel, meaning I have to wait even longer to *try* to get an image of the drive. Why is this an issue? Because sometimes `CHKDSK` can kill a hard drive's file system. It has happened to me a couple times, which put me in the habit of imaging first, checking later. Therefore, the question is, **how can I disable the automatic `CHKDSK` for secondary hard drives on bootup in Windows 8?**

Comment: Fast potential answer - not marking it as an answer because I have not personally done it. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/13f8fd32-919d-4bc9-ace3-98dd374b0e03

Comment: @MarkAllen I came across that page as well, but it seems to reset itself when I plug in other hard drives

Comment: Darn, I was afraid of that. :(

Comment: There is a registry entry you can use to disable automatic CHKDSK there are many questions that provide the entry.  This would only work if the same drive letter is always assigned.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sure it would, but because of this situation, it won't work for me :(

Comment: How about something silly like safe mode? (Probably not. xD)

Comment: @Ariane But I don't have imaging software that works in Safe Mode the way we need it to

Comment: There are a few other boot modes, I think, that you can choose from. From the General tab in the Modern UI "control panel", there's a thing for "advanced restart" which I did once. I think I vaguely remember there were many things, such as "restart in XX mode". Or hey, you look like a pro who could be able to do this. If you don't find any way to do this, you can always somehow make chkdsk not work at all. If the function is broken, Windows can't do it, right? And then you'd use the other computer if you need to perform a chkdsk. Or another Windows 8 on another partition.

Comment: Or uhm, another violent workaround. I think there are kinds of boxes you can use to turn an internal HDD into an external one, or something. I don't think it would be checking external hard drives, would it?

Comment: @Ariane I don't know about the external, we like having the setup we have, so that won't answer this question *for me*, but maybe someone else. As for the Advanced Restart, that would require me to boot the system first without the extra drive, then attempt to catch the reboot in time to shut down, plug in the drive, and power on

Comment: I'm hoping someone has a better solution.

Comment: @Ariane Me too.

Comment: Considering I have never seen any CHKDSK that didn't provide a prompt so you could skip the scan there might not be an answer to the question